# Convertir archivo .KEY a .PEM

Tags: javascript, nodejs, openssl

Necesito convertir un archivo .KEY a .PEM en nodejs corriendo en un servidor para una app, de preferencia usando la librería de openssl.

El comando que ejecuto en windows sin problema es:

```
openssl x509 -inform DER -outform PEM -in archivoDeEntrada.cer -pubkey -out archivoDeSalida.cer.pem
```

Ya probé varias librerías como [openssl-nodejs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/openssl-nodejs) y otras sin éxito. Alguien sabrá alguna manera?

Comment: Entonces la pregunta es como convertir en un servidor con Linux o como hacerlo programáticamente en nodejs?

Comment: Como hacerlo en nodejs

Comment: Podrías probar convertirlo con un comando, igual que hacías en Windows pero en Linux. Y luego cuando encuentres el comando que funciona lo puedes ejecutar desde node con el método `exec` del módulo `child_process`

Comment: Ok, investigaré s ver si me funciona. Gracias por el tip

Comment: "sin éxito" significa que obtienes el certificado convertido a PEM, pero resulta ser inválido **o** significa que te salta un error en la conversión misma? Tu pregunta debiera explicar en qué momento te salta el error y qué dice exactamente.

Comment: Ambas. Hablando de la librería openssl-nodejs, me da un error (que ya varios usuarios han preguntado en los issues sin tener respuesta). Otras ni siquiera incluyen documentación y brincan errores sin mensaje explicito y otras crean archivos vacios. Mi pregunta es si alguien ya ha usado o sabe de algún método que les sirva.